# SSH to Pi through putty Connection Refused (Raspbian Wheezy)

Tags: ssh, pi-2, ethernet, raspbian-wheezy, ethernet-port

I just got a *RPi2 Model B* a few weeks ago and just started to program with it.
I am trying to connect to the Internet for the project I am doing. So the OS is installed on my SD the only problem I am having is connecting to the ethernet and Wi-Fi.

I have installed **Raspbian Wheezy** on it. When I have the Pi hooked up to the ethernet. So I looked for the IP and found `192.168.000.011`

I open putty and have `192.168.000.011 on port 22` and `192.168.000.011 on port 23`. And no matter what I have done it will not let me ssh into it. It keeps saying Connection Refused

I have completely installed and setup the Pi with **Raspbian Wheezy.** And it is in graphical mode when I last plugged it in to my TV.

> Do I need to switch it back to the terminal or does it not matter?
>   The Main question is what is preventing me from SSHing into this device?

**NOTE 1: I have gone into `sudo raspi-config` Enabled SSH and no luck**

**NOTE 2: None of my IP's interfere with each other!!**

Comment: what is the ip of the computer you are using to connect to your pi? can you ping 192.168.0.11? It shouldn't matter but can you ssh using 192.168.0.11? What is the output of sudo service ssh status?

Comment: 'Connection Refused' is a very generic message.  
SSH is, by default, on port 22 so 23 is out of the question.  
You can connect only from your LAN; to get external (public) access you need to forward port 22 on your router to the, possibly static, RPI address and find the router's 'public IP'; in this case the IP is never on the 192.168.*.* family.

Comment: "Do I need to switch it back to the terminal" No that doesn't matter, it doesn't matter if you have it on terminal mode or on graphical mode. Are you sure you are connected at the same network where your Pi is connected to?

Comment: @SteveRobillard I know that my IP's are completely different from anything else.

Comment: @Fcm hmmm. I'm not to sure about that if all else fails I will try this.

Comment: @Michielvk I'm sure when its in headless its on the same network. I'm doing it through a Wired Connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out! I had 2 digit wrong. DCHP was not telling me correctly so I had to use nmap to find it. **`192.168.0.11`** I was using `192.168.000.11` Which was wrong. and the port works as `22`

Comment: Don't forget to mark this answer as correct (grey check mark). It's just that people know that this topic is answered.

Comment: @Michielvk I had to wait until I could mark it as an answer. It wouldn't let me till today.

Answer (score 5):

Raspbian jessie does have ssh enabled by default, I don't know if wheezy have ssh enabled by default. What I recommend doing is:

- Go to the terminal
- And type: `sudo raspi-config`
  [image: raspi-config]
  <sub>(source: [raspberrypi.org](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/images/raspi-config.png))</sub>
- Go to advanced options
  [image: raspi-config advanced options]

In the advanced options will be an option to enable/disable ssh.
[image: raspi-config advanced options ssh]

There you can enable SSH
[image: raspi-config advanced options ssh setting]

More information here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/

Comment: But I have done that already! Let me go into it again and re-setup and see if it works.

Comment: Nope. redid the config and still no luck!

Answer (score 1):

Usually this means you haven't set-up the sshd on the Pi properly (or at all) - it isn't installed by default.
Can you actually ssh from the Pi to itself (hook it back to your TV & try it)?
If not then ensure `sshd` is installed & check the config file `/etc/sshd_config` - once you can do this locally then it should work from outside - check firewalls & port-forwarding if not.

Comment: As far as I know, sshd is enabled by default in raspbian. But since OP has not mentioned which os he is using, this can be the probable cause.

Comment: I did go to this! but nothing seemed to exist here. I've read all the files. I'll try again, but this doesn't seem like it's gonna work.

Comment: @YamIanon I'm so sorry. I somehow missed that detail. Glad to know that your problem has been solved.

Comment: @dastaan It's fine. Sorry If I seemed to be rude at all. Anyway thank you for your help anyway. :D